# How do I figure out which item was selected from a dynamically created list using jQuery

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I am dynamically adding items to an ul when a page loads.

```
addUsersToDropdown = (user_markers) ->
  console.log("inside addUsersToDropdown")
  for marker in user_markers
    console.log("adding name to dropdown , name = #{marker.name}")
    jQuery("#user_list").append("<li><a onclick='return false;' href='#'> <img alt=\"#{marker.name}\" src=\"#{marker.gravatar_url}\" />  #{marker.name}</a></li>")
```

How do I figure out which item the user selected?  Everything I have seen seems to require you know the id before hand. ie

```
jQuery('#some_id')
```

Comment: That's what `$(this)` is for inside your event handler's callback

Comment: Is that [tag:coffeescript], or a horrible syntax error in your code?

Comment: yeah, it coffeescript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a click event to every one of your link messages - `this` will refer to the `<a>` tag. Which you can use to do what you want with.

```
$("#user_list a").click(function() {
    // this holds the item that was clicked.
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

**Example: http://jsfiddle.net/KXGtt/**

Comment: The typo, $("$user_list a"),  had me for a while but it was enough of a hint.

Comment: Sorry about that - I fixed it awhile ago... That's the trouble with writing code without testing it.

Answer (score -2):

```
$("$user_list li").click(function() {
    console.log(this.index);
}
```

Comment: Hi There. This may well be a great solution, but would you mind giving some explanation for how it solves the problem? Don't forget that total newbies come to Stack overflow, looking to see if this solution might help them with their problem too - and when it's explained well, they learn a lot from what they find. So even if the solution is obvious to an experienced programmer... it might not be to them.

Comment: Why did you make the same typo as caspian?